# SSRS - calculated fields

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

is there any way to use calculated fields from one table to another table?

i have two dataset, one called tools, and the second called lots.
i have two different tables, in the tools table i have 2 col (department, product) and i created group expression and then in the third col i calculated count of  tools group by department & product.
i want to use this calculated field in the lot table.
there is a way to do it?

Comment: Are the two datasets using the same database?

Comment: no, different database

Comment: Hmm..maybe you should look at sub-tables.

Comment: When you talk about tables, are you talking about a tablix, or a dataset.

Comment: i mean tablix not dataset

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. You can refer to it within the containing group by using ReportItems!<>.Value, however you cannot refer to it outside that group I.E. in your other table.

Can you re-write the query that builds the dataset to use `GROUP BY` and perform the calculation via SQL? You can then use `LookUp()` to refer to it even in tables that are based on your lot dataset instead of the tools one (provided there is some common key that you can use to match on, like department and product)

Comment: thanks, i re-write my query and now its works perfect